# Como saber o tipo do objeto DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se via JS ou Jquery, existe um jeito de eu identificar o tipo do objeto DOM que eu estou manipulando.

Por exemplo, faço o seguinte seletor: `$('#filtos select, #filtos input').each(function (index, obj).....);`

Dentro deste `each` vou ter objetos `<select>`, `<input>` do tipo `text`, `checkbox` entre outros. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma propriedade que me diz qual o tipo desses elementos.

Comment: [obj.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

Comment: @BrunoRB , é isso mesmo obrigado. Pode responder a pergunta, sem ser como comentário.

Comment: Pra que você precisa disso? Nesse caso não seria melhor fazer dois seletores separados? Ou talvez possa usar uma função em comum ao invés de fazer coisas diferentes para cada tipo de campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use algo assim:

```
$('#filtos select, #filtos input').each(function (index, obj) {
    var $this = $(obj)

    var meu_elemento = $this[0].tagName;

     if (meu_elemento == 'input') {
          var meu_tipo = $this.attr('type');
     }        
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_tagname.asp